# Help identify a couple of album cover fonts from 1975

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I can't exactly identify either font used for "Eagles" or "Lyin' Eyes." 
Does anyone have ideas?
[image: Lyin' Eyes by the Eagles]

Comment: Possibly not a _digital_ font, as the use of computer graphics wasn't so widespread back then.